# Javascript - Get Id from innerHTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a `function` which creates new elements in a for loop. For example, I want a div for every item in an array. But I need the ID of the created html div-tag to trigger another function.
This is what I currently got:

```js
      function change() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        let modal = document.createElement('div');
        let a = '<div id="id'+i+'"> innerHTML </div>';
        modal.innerHTML = a;
        // document.getElementById(a.this.id).innerHTML = "get by id";
        document.getElementById('test').appendChild(
          modal
        );

        }
      }
```

```html
    <div class="test" id="test">test</div>
    <button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

I need to get the id of every div which is created onclick.

I tried to to like `document.getElementById('id' + i).innerHTML = "do something";` but this doesnt work. Someone have a solution for my problem? jQuery is also an option!

Comment: `document.getElementById('id' + i).innerHTML = "do something";` should absolutely work for you, assuming the value of `i` matches. That said, a better idea would be to use a common class on the new content and relate it to the event using DOM traversal. We'd need to understand when the HTML should be changed in order to show you an example of that, though

Comment: I tried but it throws error **Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null** @RoryMcCrossan if I click Change button.

Comment: @ViLuWi Put that statement after `.appendChild`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('test').appendChild(modal); document.getElementById('id' + i).innerHTML = "get by id";`

Comment: Ok now it works.. thanks!

Comment: @ViLuWi Happy to help.

Comment: Why not just use createElement for the anchor and no need to look it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `document.getElementById` after the element has been added to the DOM.

```
//...
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(modal); 
document.getElementById('id' + i).innerHTML = "get by id";
//...
```